# Secure wifi connection with FreeRADIUS, MySQL, EAP-PEAP, TLS

Tags: wireless-networking, security, mysql, freeradius, peap

I'm trying to setup a wireless network as shown in the picture and I'm struggling how to secure it.

Picture of Wifi Network:

[image]

My basic question is: How I can securely store passwords into MySQL database so that FreeRADIUS can read it?

Here's a longer version what I want to accomplish:

1. User connects to wireless network
2. User will be prompt for a username and password
3. With right credentials RADIUS server will send a certificate and TLS connection can be formed.

I've got the setup working with Cleartext-passwords, but obviously I'd like to secure the passwords with some kind of hash. Now the passwords are stored as clear text even in the database. From this compatibility table I've understood if I use PEAP with MSCHAPv2 I need to use NT hash passwords. http://deployingradius.com/documents/protocols/compatibility.html

When I add a user with daloRADIUS there's only options for Cleartext-, User-, Crypt-, MD5-, SHA1- and CHAP-Password. There's no option for NT hash password. I guess this means I can't use daloRADIUS as a web GUI. I've thought that I'll just make a shell script which will easily add and remove users in the database.

In FreeRADIUS I've configured `/etc/freeradius/mods-available/eap`

```
eap {
    default_eap_type = peap
peap {
    default_eap_type = mschapv2
```

If I've understood correctly, I'm now using EAP-PEAP with MSCHAPv2 and TLS. I know I'm using TLS because with the first login attempt to wireless network freeradius `-X` debugging mode gives the error below. After attempting TLS the user will be asked for username and password.

```
(28) eap_peap: <<< TLS 1.2  [length 0002]
(28) eap_peap: ERROR: TLS Alert read:fatal:unknown CA 
(28) eap_peap: ERROR: TLS_accept: Failed in SSLv3 read client certificate A
(28) eap_peap: ERROR: SSL says: error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
(28) eap_peap: ERROR: SSL_read failed inside of TLS (-1), TLS session failed
(28) eap_peap: ERROR: TLS receive handshake failed during operation
(28) eap_peap: ERROR: [eaptls process] = fail
(28) eap: ERROR: Failed continuing EAP PEAP (25) session.  EAP sub-module failed
(28) eap: Sending EAP Failure (code 4) ID 162 length 4
(28) eap: Failed in EAP select
```

With Cleartext-Password authentication works but when I try to put some kind of hashed password the authentication fails as seen below.

```
(36)   Found Auth-Type = EAP
(36)   # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/inner-tunnel
(36)     authenticate {
(36) eap: Expiring EAP session with state 0x024362c402167826
(36) eap: Finished EAP session with state 0x024362c402167826
(36) eap: Previous EAP request found for state 0x024362c402167826, released from the list
(36) eap: Peer sent packet with method EAP MSCHAPv2 (26)
(36) eap: Calling submodule eap_mschapv2 to process data
(36) eap_mschapv2: # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/inner-tunnel
(36) eap_mschapv2:   Auth-Type MS-CHAP {
(36) mschap: WARNING: No Cleartext-Password configured.  Cannot create NT-Password
(36) mschap: WARNING: No Cleartext-Password configured.  Cannot create LM-Password
(36) mschap: Creating challenge hash with username: joujou
(36) mschap: Client is using MS-CHAPv2
(36) mschap: ERROR: FAILED: No NT/LM-Password.  Cannot perform authentication
(36) mschap: ERROR: MS-CHAP2-Response is incorrect
(36)     [mschap] = reject
(36)   } # Auth-Type MS-CHAP = reject
(36) eap: Sending EAP Failure (code 4) ID 85 length 4
```

So could you help me, what options do I have for hashing the passwords?

Here's the software and hardware I'm using:

- Mainly Windows 10 laptops
- TP-Link Archer C7 v2 wireless access points, running with OpenWRT Chaos Calmer 15.05 / Luci (git-15.248.30277-3836b45)
- 2 ESXi virtual machines: one is running PfSense 2.2.6 and the other one is running Ubuntu Server 14.04.
- On Ubuntu Server I've installed FreeRADIUS 3.0.10 with MySQL and daloRADIUS 0.9-9.

Comment: For MSCHAPv2, just like the table says, you have exactly two options: unhashed or NT hashed.

Comment: Is there a way to store passwords in the database more securely than just NT hash (aka NTLM)? It doesn't really matter if the passwords are clear or NT hashed because cracking NT hash is so easy.


When user would connect to wifi, the passwords would be converted to NT hash for authentication, so if somebody would be sniffing the password while authentication they'd only get one password.

Comment: How exactly would you "convert" one hash to another?

Comment: I was thinking that maybe the NT hash could be hashed and salted with another cryptographic hashing method and this new hash would be stored in the database. Of course there would need to be some software reading the extra hashed password, but I guess there's no software for doing this.

Side note: I got the NT hash passwords working with my setup by adding them by hand to the database. daloRADIUS doesn't support NT hash (or NT-Password as it's called in FreeRADIUS) so I'll just drop that from my setup.

Comment: And, um, when you need the NT hash for MS-CHAPv2, how are you going to extract it from the "new" hash?

Comment: That's what I'm asking if there's some method for doing this. I think that storing the passwords as NT hash (aka NTLM hash aka NT-Password) in the database is a big security flaw. But maybe I've just got to live with that and make some kind of check that the users are not using same password for wifi and more critical systems.

Comment: If you use MS-CHAPv2, there really isn't. Your only other option is to require PAP via EAP-TTLS.